# how can i fix npm install issues?

Tags: node.js, npm

hey i am having issues with `npm install`.  I am getting errors. How can i fix it?

```
npm install
npm WARN config global `--global`, `--local` are deprecated. Use `--location=global` instead.
npm WARN ERESOLVE overriding peer dependency
npm WARN While resolving: @use-it/event-listener@0.1.6
npm WARN Found: react@17.0.2
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm WARN   32 more (@devexpress/dx-react-core, ...)
npm WARN
npm WARN Could not resolve dependency:
npm WARN peer react@"^16.8.0" from @use-it/event-listener@0.1.6
npm WARN node_modules/@use-it/event-listener
npm WARN   @use-it/event-listener@"^0.1.2" from use-dark-mode@2.3.1
npm WARN   node_modules/use-dark-mode
npm WARN   1 more (use-persisted-state)
npm WARN
npm WARN Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm WARN node_modules/react
npm WARN   peer react@"^16.8.0" from @use-it/event-listener@0.1.6
npm WARN   node_modules/@use-it/event-listener
npm WARN     @use-it/event-listener@"^0.1.2" from use-dark-mode@2.3.1
npm WARN     node_modules/use-dark-mode
npm WARN     1 more (use-persisted-state)
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: prettierrc@0.0.0-5
npm ERR! Found: prettier@2.3.2
npm ERR! node_modules/prettier
npm ERR!   prettier@"^2.3.2" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer prettier@"^1.3.1" from prettierrc@0.0.0-5
npm ERR! node_modules/prettierrc
npm ERR!   prettierrc@"0.0.0-5" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: prettier@1.19.1
npm ERR! node_modules/prettier
npm ERR!   peer prettier@"^1.3.1" from prettierrc@0.0.0-5
npm ERR!   node_modules/prettierrc
npm ERR!     prettierrc@"0.0.0-5" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\{user}\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-06-22T15_37_55_849Z-debug-0.log
```

Comment: You can do what it says: *Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.*

Comment: @DanielB my issue is finding meaning in the error messages. Ex: it "could not resolve dependency" of package "prettier". It appears prettierrc@0.0.0-5 has a dependency on prettier@^1.3.1. It found prettier@^2.3.2 in node_modules/prettier. So... whats the deal? 2.3.2 is higher than 1.3.1. Does ^1.3.1 mean up to 1.999.999 but not 2.0.0? how will --force fix it? Will it install 1.3.1 additionally just for prettierrc?

Comment: @Alex You can try for yourself [in the interactive semver calculator](https://semver.npmjs.com/). `--force` does what it says: “accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution”. It simply ignores these conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

use `npm i --force` or `npm i ----legacy-peer-deps` to fix mult react version conflict.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).